# MSP-FET UART loopback

Tags: microcontroller, uart, msp430

I'm trying to use the uart on an [MSP-FET](https://www.ti.com/tool/MSP-FET) to connect to a custom-made board. But I stumble on the first hurdle - getting some traffic through the uart.

I'm bridging pins 12 and 14 (TX and RX) and all other pins are disconnected. I was expecting to be able to loop some data, but I don't get anything.

I'm running Ubuntu Linux 20.4 and I get two tty's - ttyACM0 and ttyACM1. But none of them responds when I connect using minicom.

I have tested with an FTDI serial adapter, and that one works fine. (ttyUSB0)

(MSP-FET = MSP MCU Programmer and Debugger by Texas Instruments, used for developing devices based on MSP430 microcontrollers. It utilises a 14 pin connector with jtag, Spy-Bi-Wire and uart interfaces. )

Comment: Had to look up what a "MSP-FET" is, so added a link to your question :)

Comment: Which MSP-FET? And which connector?

Comment: @CL Sorry, I didn't know that there were more than one product called MSP-FET. See the link that Marcus Müller so kindly added. I'm also adding a short description in case the link breaks in future.

Comment: Are you trying to use 9600 baud? What happens if you switch to a higher rate?

Comment: @CL It started working at 38400. Thank you. Why wouldn't it work on lower baud rates? Or rather, what made you come up with the suggestion to increase the rate?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue. The problem is that you have to "activate" the COM port. One way to do it is starting a debug session in CCS. Other option is using the [MSPFlasher](https://www.ti.com/tool/MSP430-FLASHER) and executing the order MSPFlasher -z [VCC].